# Performing statistics on multiple columns of data

Tags: r, loops, statistics, multiple-columns

I'm trying to conduct certain statistics such as t-tests on a table of data containing hundreds to thousands of columns. The data is formatted in a way that the two groups of values  I'm comparing **are in the same column**.

So, basically my first attempt was to cut and paste like the following;

```
NN <-read.delim("E:/output.txt")
View(NN)
attach(NN)

#output p-values of 100 t-tests 
sink(file="E:/ttest.txt", append=TRUE, split=FALSE)
t.test(Tree1[1:13],Tree1[14:34])$p.value
t.test(Tree2[1:13],Tree2[14:34])$p.value
t.test(Tree3[1:13],Tree3[14:34])$p.value
```

....
...
..
.

As my data grows, this is becoming more and more impractical. Is there a way to loop these t-tests through each column sequentially and save the ouput to file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are `Tree1`, `Tree2`, etc?

Comment: @Dwin - you encouraged me to add a disclaimer to my answer - well done.

Comment: @Jack Tree1, Tree2, etc are just the column names.

Answer (score 6):

`lapply` will get you there I think with an anonymous function:

```
> test <- data.frame(a=1:100,b=101:200)
> lapply(test,function(x) t.test(x[1:50],x[51:100])$p.value)
$a
[1] 2.876776e-31

$b
[1] 2.876776e-31
```

I should do my part for good practice and also note that running 100 t-tests in a single go is fraught with the potential for type-1 errors and other badness.
Extracting the p-value in isolation is also probably a really bad move.

Comment: "note that running 100 t-tests in a single go is fraught with the potential for type-1 errors" +1 for the warning.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is a wise approach or if it even works correctly but try `mapply` with the indexed parts as in:

```
test <- data.frame(a=1:100,b=101:200)

testa <- test[1:50, ]
testb <- test[51:100, ]
t.test2 <- function(x, y) t.test(x, y)[["p.value"]]
mapply(t.test2, testa, testb)
```

*EDIT: I used thelatemail's data so it's comparable.  His warning is right on.*

Answer (score -3):

Thanks for all the input. Just a few clarifications; while I AM running hundreds of t-tests at once, they are comparing independent sets of data each time. So for example, the values in column 1 (Tree1), rows 1:50 would only be compared once to rows 51:100 in the same column, and never used again. The same for column 2 (Tree2), and so on. Would type-1 error still be a problem? the way I see it I'm basically doing t-tests on separate data sets one at a time.

That being said, I've come up with a way to do this with a for-loop, and the results correspond to those when t-testing each column individually.

```
for (i in 1:100)

  print (t.test(mydata[1:50, i],mydata[51:100, i])$p.value)

end;
```

The only problem being that my output always has a [1] in front of it.

Comment: Why use a `for` loop then? The answer I posted using `lapply` gives the exact same results but will also print out the variable label as well. It also doesn't require having to specify `1:ncol(mydata)` like the `for` solution does. Also, why do you have an `end;` statement?  It is an entirely different function relating to timeseries data in R! To clarify re: type 1 errors, it doesn't matter if each set of data is independent. Digging through 100 sets of analyses for a significant result with no targeted, prior reasoning is just asking to find spurious results.